# Serialize java.util.Enumeration

Tags: java, serialization

How could I `serialize` `Enumeration` object to a file and then `deserialize` it? I tried to convert it to `ArrayList` but this option doesn't work for me. I tried the following code:

```
FileOutputStream fos            = null;
ObjectOutputStream outs         = null;
Enumeration<TreePath> stateEnum = com.jidesoft.tree.TreeUtils.saveExpansionStateByTreePath(tree);
ArrayList<TreePath> pathList    = new ArrayList<TreePath>();

while(stateEnum.hasMoreElements()){
    pathList.add(stateEnum.nextElement());
}
try {
    fos = new FileOutputStream(TREE_STATE_FILE);
    outs = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    outs.writeObject(pathList);
    outs.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    _log.info("Failed to create " + TREE_STATE_FILE + " file: ", e);
}
```

But when I tried to `serialize` it I get nulls.
Thanks

Comment: http://www.vineetmanohar.com/2010/01/3-ways-to-serialize-java-enums/

Comment: I'm talking about java.util.Enumeration interface

Comment: "this option doesn't work for me" is very vague. Please give more details of what you've tried (with code samples) and what went wrong.

Comment: @Feras Odeh, Ah, too bad for you :)

Comment: @FerasOdeh: What do you mean *exactly* by "I get nulls"? Have you verified that you've copied everything to the ArrayList correctly? Does TreePath itself support serialization? Is the problem when you *deserialize* again?

Comment: @JonSkeet I have verified TreePath  Supports Serialization So it should not Return null unless file is getting created correctly and there is something in that list.

Comment: @AmitD: You still haven't said exactly what *is* returning null. It would help if you'd stick to built-in types for the purpose of demonstrating the problem - if you could provide a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem with (say) an `Enumeration` of strings, that would be good.

Comment: Did you considered saving the ordinal values instead?

Comment: @FerasOdeh: Where is the `TreePath` object coming from? It's not the one from javax.swing.tree, is it? Is the object serializable?

Comment: @FerasOdeh  I have created a sample program using and it works properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this what you mean but take a look at this code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class SerializableEnumeration
   extends ArrayList
   implements Enumeration
{
   /** The serialVersionUID */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 8678951571196067510L;
   private int index;

   public SerializableEnumeration () {
      index = 0;
   }

   public SerializableEnumeration (Collection c) {
      super(c);
      index = 0;
   }

   public SerializableEnumeration (int initialCapacity) {
      super(initialCapacity);
      index = 0;
   }

   public boolean hasMoreElements() {
      return (index < size());
   }

   public Object nextElement() throws NoSuchElementException
   {
      try {
         Object nextObj = get(index);
         index++;
         return nextObj;
      }
      catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
         throw new NoSuchElementException();
      }
   }

   private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out)
      throws java.io.IOException
   {
      // the only thing to write is the index field
      out.defaultWriteObject();
   }

   private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
      throws java.io.IOException, ClassNotFoundException
   {
      in.defaultReadObject();
   }
}
```

From [here](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0140__Collections/SerializableEnumeration.htm)

Answer (score 1):

IMO, serialization of `Enumeration` does not really make much sense. An `Enumeration` is  merely a floating view on top of a data structure or other business logic. In order to serialize, you would better stick to serializing the backing interface. To visualize what I'm writing, I set up a little code snippet:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.tree.TreePath;

public class EnumTest {

  public class MyEnumerator<T> {

    // set holding data
    List<T> data;

    public MyEnumerator(List<T> data) {
      this.data = data;
    }

    public List<T> getData() {
      return data;
    }

    public Enumeration<T> enumerate() {
      return new Enumeration<T>() {
        transient int i = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasMoreElements() {
          return i < data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public T nextElement() {
          return data.get(i++);
        }
      };
    }
  }

  public EnumTest() throws Exception {
    List<TreePath> TreePaths = Arrays.asList(new TreePath[] { new TreePath("3"), new TreePath("4"), new TreePath("5") });
    MyEnumerator<TreePath> myEnum1 = new MyEnumerator<TreePath>(TreePaths);
    print(myEnum1);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.out");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(myEnum1.getData());
    oos.close();
    fos.close();

    System.out.println("* Serialization complete");

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("test.out");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<TreePath> data = (List<TreePath>) ois.readObject();
    MyEnumerator<TreePath> myEnum2 = new MyEnumerator<TreePath>(data);
    print(myEnum2);

    System.out.println("* Deserialization complete");
  }

  private void print(MyEnumerator<TreePath> myEnum1) {
    Enumeration<TreePath> enm = myEnum1.enumerate();
    while (enm.hasMoreElements()) {
      System.out.println(enm.nextElement());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new EnumTest();
  }
}
```

This works around the topic of serializing the `Enumeration` itself by persisting the contained data and reconstructing the wrapper class `MyEnumerator` afterwards. Through the serialization / deserialization loop you will get a different object which is however semantically identical.

Comment: the first paragraph explanation sounds reasonable. Although I would change the statement  'you would better stick to serializing the backing interface' a little to 'the backing object instead of interface.

Comment: @Atul: Granted, and I alsow was thinking about that, but decided against it, since this narrows the scope very much down. I'm usually working with `Iterator` (the successor of `Enumeration`) to implement techniques like lazy loading while in the same time hiding the actual backing _cascade / service_ implementation from the consumer side. Behind an `Iterator`, I can have multiple objects, collections, local services or even remote service interfaces. So maybe the best way to say it, is that `Enumeration` actually makes no statement about where the data comes from as long as it's enumeratable.

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work TreePath also has to be serializable, since the elements of pathList are TreePath objects.

Comment: [TreePath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html?is-external=true) is serializable. Check [saveExpansionStateByTreePath](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/tree/TreeUtils.html#saveExpansionStateByTreePath%28javax.swing.JTree%29)

Comment: The elements of stateEnum may be null, or serialization for TreePath is broken and null is written instead.

Comment: If you are reading in javax.swing.tree.TreePath objects from another version of Swing this comment from the Java docs is relevant:  
 "Warning: Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases. The current serialization support is appropriate for short term storage or RMI between applications running the same version of Swing. As of 1.4, support for long term storage of all JavaBeansTM has been added to the java.beans package. Please see XMLEncoder."

Comment: I have checked that it gets serialized properly. Please check example uploaded above by me.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why he would be getting **multiple** nulls when serializing.  Your example works, so I guess the elements of the enumeration are null references.